# Can I connect 2 network in 1 router and switch?

Tags: networking

Is it possible for a wan topology work like the one on the image where 2 networks are connected via router but using only one switch?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
This is a totally normal network topology generally known as a "router on a stick" configuration.

But to do it properly the router and the switch must support VLAN's (Virtual LAN). (Also known as .1q support as the ethernet standard for this is known as 802.1q).
Each ip-subnet gets it's own VLAN. The switch is configured so that LAN-ports belong to either vlan 1 or vlan 2 depending on what is connected to those LAN ports.
The link between router and switch is configured as a so-called "trunk" that carries BOTH vlan's.
The router then routes between those as if they were on separate physical interfaces.